# Why is UserRolesPartRecord not derived from ContentPartRecord in Orchard CMS?

Tags: c#, orchardcms

I want to use `IContentManager` to query some users with the following conditions

1. published
2. member of specific role

By using `IContentManager.Query(VersionOptions)` i can implement condition 1 easily but i can't find a way to implement condition 2 as all other generic extension methods are restricted to record classes derived from `ContentPartRecord`.

Is there a reason why `UserRolesPartRecord` not derived from `ContentPartRecord` thus hindering me from using it in content manager queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it's old. Last time I had to perform complex queries on users, I had to resort to HQL, not `ContentManager.Query`. Check out these blog posts: https://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/querying-orchard-in-hql, https://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/joining-orchard-part-records-in-hql, https://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/getting-orchard-content-items-out-of-hql. The end result looks something like this:

```
var session = _sessionLocator.For(typeof (UserPartRecord));

const string fromTables =
    "FROM Orchard.ContentManagement.Records.ContentItemVersionRecord ItemVersion"
    + " JOIN ItemVersion.ContentItemRecord Item"
    + " JOIN Item.UserPartRecord User"
    + " WHERE ItemVersion.Published = true"
    + " AND User.UserName IS NOT NULL";
const whereClause =
    "User.Id NOT IN (SELECT Role.UserId FROM Orchard.Roles.Models.UserRolesPartRecord Role)";
const orderBy = "ORDER BY User.UserName";

var pageQuery = session.CreateQuery(
    "SELECT DISTINCT User.Id, User.UserName "
    + fromTables
    + " AND " + whereClause
    + " " + orderBy)
    .SetFirstResult(pager.GetStartIndex())
    .SetMaxResults(takeNum);

var ids = pageQuery.List<int>();

var results = contentManager
    .GetMany<UserPart>(ids, VersionOptions.AllVersions, QueryHints.Empty);
```